# Docker container with Flask App: Can't access my application

Tags: docker, flask, http-status-code-404, port

It is very confusing. I have been trying from number of days with all instructions found on stack overflow and web. But nothing is working.

```
$ docker inspect app_flask_1|grep Address
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "IPAddress": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
                "IPAddress": "172.20.0.2",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.6
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./flaskapp/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --user
COPY ./flaskapp .
COPY ./app.py .

EXPOSE 5000
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV DATABASE=/data/master.db

CMD ["flask", "run", "-h", "0.0.0.0"]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  flask:
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    image: webapp-flask
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
```

I have tried all.

```
  http://172.20.0.2/
  http://127.0.0.1:5000/
  http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

Appears app is hosted on http://127.0.0.1:5000/. But shows 404 not found.

```
Attaching to app_flask_1
flask_1  |  * Serving Flask app "app.py"
flask_1  |  * Environment: production
flask_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
flask_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
flask_1  |  * Debug mode: off
flask_1  |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
flask_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2020 19:54:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
flask_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2020 19:54:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: You probably want to do that `pip install --upgrade pip --user` before you install requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The fact of seeing

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

in the logs shows that your application is running, but the framework isn't finding a route for `/`. There can be a number of reasons for this, with the most likely being a missing

```
@app.route('/')
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! It worked perfectly well. Accidentally, I deleted a line of code which fetch the routes. I thought application has worked well without docker, I might have made mistake in docker implementation.